# Datamodel for Survey Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-modeling

I'm working on an Online Survey Form and a Question Builder.

You create different of question groups via the Question Builder by dragging(drag N drop) In Yes/No-questions, OptionLists and Text-input-fields. This Is how the Questionbuilder looks like:

[image]

After you have created this groups with Questions, you can populate the Survey form with this Question groups. After you have created the Survey Form and added the groups of questions, the form should be assigned to all the users In the system.

I want your input on my Data-model how this should work. Below you can see my models. The thing I am worried about is how the Answer-model should work.

```
QuestionContainer
---------------
public int ID { get; set; }
public string QuestionerContainerName { get; set; }
public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

Question
--------------
public int ID { get; set; }
public string QuestionHeader { get; set; }
public string QuestionHelpText { get; set; }
public string QuestionText { get; set; }
public virtual List<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }

QuestionOption
---------------
public string OptionText { get; set; }
public int RiskScore { get; set; }
public Question NestedQuestion {get; set;}
```

The QuestionOption Is the different of answer options/alternatives a question has.

Here comes the models for the Form Survey:

```
FormModel
-----------------
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string IntroTitle { get; set; }
public string IntroText { get; set; }
public string SupportName { get; set; }
public string SupportPhone { get; set; }

public virtual FormSection FormSections { get; set; }

FormSection
----------------------
public LicenseHolderModel LicenseHolder { get; set; }
public List<GasStationModel> GasStations { get; set; }
public List<Question> FormQuestions1 { get; set; }
public List<Question> FormQuestions2 { get; set; }

SurveyAnswers(Is this Ok??)
-----------------------
public int ID {get; set}
public int SurveyFormId {get; set;}
public int QuestionOptionId {get; set;}
public string Answer {get; set;}
```

I am seeking some input for this. Have I missed something? As I said, I'm not sure if I have got the Answer-model right. I want to store the answer on each question that the user has entered in the form.